# Windows equivalent of /dev/disk/by-path/ on Linux

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I would like to be able to identify disks on a Windows machine by their location, i.e. which port they have been plugged into.  On Linux I can do this easily by looking at the contents of the /dev/disk/by-path/ directory.  I am struggling to find a way to do this under Windows.  I can see that Device Manager does what I want when you select the View by Connection option.

I am looking for a way to do that programmatically from C++.  The disks may have no partitions on them, or the partitions may not contain filesystems recognized by Windows so all the functions that deal with disk volumes and drive letters are out.

The requirement is that no matter how many disks are added or removed I can still identify the disks that are present, and which port they have been attached to.  Does anybody have any ideas how I might do this ?

Comment: You could use the SetupDi API to enumerate devices in the `DISK` class (GUID should be `{4D36E967-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}`) and then look at their parents in the device tree to figure out their connection.

Comment: in powershell you can use Get-Disk. For example `(Get-Disk).Location`, `Get-Disk | select Location, FriendlyName`, `Get-Disk | select *`... I don't know what the exact API under the hood though

Comment: call `CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW` with `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK`

Comment: @RbMM Thanks, using `CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW` seems to work nicely. I have 2 disks which are attached to a JMicron USB to SATA adapter which the Powershell `(Get-Disk).Location` command mentioned by @phuclv returned the same location for both disks, but `CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW`  returns 2 different strings: `\\?\SCSI#Disk&Ven_JMicron&Prod_Tech#6&89614d7&0&000000#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}` and `\\?\SCSI#Disk&Ven_JMicron&Prod_Tech#6&89614d7&0&000001#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}`.